# How to move long ternary operator from my Blade view to a controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

The ternary operator:

```
<div class='votingContainer'>
    <a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 1 ) ? "liked" : "like" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
    <a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 0 ) ? "disliked" : "dislike" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
</div>
```

This does the following - it checks if the currently authenticated user has voted for the current image and if he has voted, a `liked` class is added to the `<a>` element which prevents the user from liking it again. If he hasn't voted, a `like` class is added to the `<a>` element which allows him to vote.

The logic is more or less the same for the second `<a>` element except this time it's for disliking.

Unfortunately, I am not sure how to move the long ternary operator from my blade view to a controller. I have a PagesController.php in which I return the view and pass the images:

```
public function index(){
    $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    return view('home', ['images' => $images]);
}
```

And I also have ImagesController.php in which I have my `uploadImage()` and `deleteImage()` functions.

Is it possible to somehow move this logic from my view to a controller?

Comment: Is votes a relationship on Image?

Comment: How about moving the logic into the image model? You could create something like votedLiked() and votedDisliked(), you could pass in the user to separate dependencies

Comment: @Devon Yes, My Image and User models have hasMany relationship to Vote

Comment: Assign `auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()` to a variable, or a function so you don't have to call it multiple times. `->first()` executes a DB query, so you're currently running 4 extra queries on that page... That's pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to iterate over `$images` and pass additional attribute 'class' to array with images and in blade just do:

```
    <a href='#' class='vote {{ $image->classlike }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
    <a href='#' class='vote {{ $image->classdislike }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
```

At controller:

```
$images = $images->map(function ($image) {
    $image['classlike'] = ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 1 ) ? "liked" : "like";
    $image['classdislike'] = ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 0 ) ? "disliked" : "dislike";
    return $image;
});
```

With using @Devon method you can do it in this optimalized way:

```
$images = Image::with(['votes' => function($q) { 
    $q->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id); 
}])
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();

$images = $images->map(function ($image) {
    $image['classlike'] = ( $image->votes->first() && $image->votes->first()->vote == 1 ) ? "liked" : "like";
    $image['classdislike'] = ( $image->votes->first() && $image->votes->first()->vote == 0 ) ? "disliked" : "dislike";
    return $image;
});

return view('home', ['images' => $images]);
```

Comment: So before passing the $images to my view, I'd first have to loop through them, determine whether the user has liked/disliked or not voted at all, and add that information to the $images array and then pass it to my view?

Comment: @Bobimaru yes look at example

Comment: I'm not sure why but I'm getting "Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$id" because of "$q->where('user_id', auth()->id);"

Comment: @Bobimaru He missed, try, updated: `auth()->user()->id`

Comment: Yeah, it's `auth()->id()`, it's a method not a property, sorry

Comment: Yes it works perfectly now and that eager loading + mapping seems really handy. So I assume this combo of eager loading + mapping is more or less an efficient way of doing that?

Comment: Great! More efficient because you make less queries :)

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. Sadly I can only accept one answer even though you both contributed greatly ;(

Answer (score 3):

I like khartnett's idea of handling this in the model but for efficiency sake, especially if dealing with many images, you could eager load the votes relationship from the controller with a condition matching the current user.

```
$images = Image::with(['votes' => function($q) { $q->where('user_id', auth()->id()); }])
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Then each Image would have a collection for votes by that user:

```
$vote = $image->votes->first();
```

So while it doesn't completely solve your problem, the best part about this is it would only require 2 queries as opposed to n+1 queries.